# Sometimes, Heroku shows application error for my Express.js app

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku

Sometimes it works (can navigate to my api on my deployed Express.js app) and sometimes it doesn't (application error shown instead). The Express app I made started with express generator command which generates a default express project with home page. What also comes in mind is that the port is not defined inside the app.js but rather in the www file inside the bin folder. Here how it looks like (in fact, you can enter the command to generate express to have almost the same solution project as mine, but the www will absolutely be the same):

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

I put "web: node ./bin/www" on my Procfile which is on the root of my project because the www is located inside the bin folder.:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

On package.json I have

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

I followed the instructions clearly in following order:

```
heroku login
git init
heroku git:remote -a myapp
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

At first launching the app, everything works, my homepage, the api, etc. but after some time, when I surf to my app, I get application error, and after that, it works again, etc.

Here is the error I get by entering "heroku logs --tail" command:

```
2019-05-13T21:10:42.528090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/items" host=fmjapi.herokuapp.com request_id=d8b9ad7b-73f5-42fa-915e-c4da9e0660
c5 fwd="109.128.144.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-13T21:10:42.765654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fmjapi.herokuapp.com request_id=4767c4a4-3fcf-4bca-bb09-cb208a5e
e443 fwd="109.128.144.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It says desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/items" which I assume the problem should be within the items file. But it's soo strange that sometimes it works flawlessly so I doubt it but anyway, here it is:

**Items.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connection = require('../db');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    connection.dbConnection.query(connection.QUERIES[0], function (error, result) {
        if (error) res.sendStatus(500);
        else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    })
});

router.put('/:id/found', function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params['id'];
    let isFound = parseInt(req.body.isFound);

    if (isFound !== 1) return res.sendStatus(400);

    connection.dbConnection.query(connection.QUERIES[1], [isFound, id], function (error) {
        if (error) res.sendStatus(500);
        else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    })
});

router.put('/:id/searching', function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params['id'];
    let searching = parseInt(req.body.searching);

    if (searching !== 1) return res.sendStatus(400);

    connection.dbConnection.query(connection.QUERIES[2], [searching, id], function (error, result) {
        if (error) res.sendStatus(500);
        else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

the connection.QUERIES[number] you see above are just sql queries I defined inside an array QUERIES in db.js

And whenever my deployed app is working: this is what I get from heroku logs --tail command:

```
2019-05-13T21:23:31.919159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/items/" host=fmjapi.herokuapp.com request_id=c4dc809d-2418-494c-a2a6-6a259bab3c0e fwd="109.128.144.114" dyn
o=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=304 bytes=325 protocol=https
2019-05-13T21:23:31.915276+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/items/ 304 23.439 ms - -
```

Not to mention, this project already undergone git init for other remote repositories, but then I deleted those older remotes because I didn't need those anymore. So the only remote repo my project is connected to is the heroku.

Oh and last thing: I'm using free edition of Heroku.

**UPDATE**

I deleted

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

from my package.json and commit and pushed it against to heroku. And guess what? It works without it! Looks like the script run from Procfile was enough. Maybe it has something to do with double same script runs on both package.json as on Procfile? This could be the cause of breaking the app sometimes.

**UPDATE 2**

I removed the script run code from package json and only let Procfile's code to be run. Sadly, I still get this application error.

Comment: it says app crashed and it gives you the path of the request where it crashed I would assume you have an error there causing it to crash but we have no clue what the code is there to see

Comment: @Garret I've updated my question, sorry.